# How to Whitelist AWS Beanstalk IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My utility deployed on AWS beanstalk and push some data in one of our client's DB server. Client wants public IP of beanstalk instance for whitelisting but problem is beanstalk is on autoscaling mode and spawn instances dynamically.
Is there any way to get rid of this situation?

Answer (score 0):

One way to assign static IP from the pool and associate static IP during launch time from user data, but will not recommend this approach seems easy to go with the existing server, all you need create some elastic IP and update user data in elastic beanstalk instance.

[using-features-user-data](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html)

But you may be intrested the recommended approach here.

**How do I assign a static source IP address for all instances in a load balanced Elastic Beanstalk environment?**

**Short Description**

> You can use a network address translation (NAT) gateway to map
> multiple IP addresses into a single publicly exposed IP address. When
> your Elastic Beanstalk environment uses a NAT gateway, the backend
> instances in your environment are launched in private subnets. All
> outbound traffic from these instances is routed through the NAT
> gateway. All outbound traffic originating from your backend instances
> can be uniquely identified by an Elastic IP address, which is a static
> IP address required by the NAT gateway.

**Resolution**

> In the following steps, your Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2)
> instances are launched in a private subnet that uses a NAT gateway,
> with an attached Elastic IP address, as a default route. The load
> balancer is in a public subnet and all external traffic to and from
> the load balancer is routed through an internet gateway.
>
> For the Network card, choose Modify.
>
> For VPC, choose your VPC. In the
> Load balancer settings section, for Visibility, choose Public. In the
> Load balancer subnets table, choose the public subnets. In the
> Instance settings section, clear Public IP address. In the Instance
> subnets table, choose only private subnets with the NAT gateway that
> you set up earlier.

For more details, you can look into this [elastic-beanstalk-static-IP-address](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-static-IP-address/)

Comment: so all inbound and outbound traffic flow through static IP? correct me if I am wrong. And after successful implementation of this how load balancing works because all inbound calls and outbound calls land on single IP?

Comment: Its outbound call that will elastic ip where all inbound from LB to instance  will be using LB ip as instance we will be behind NAT,

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am trying to do the same thing but beanstalk throwing error that "At least two subnets should be in two different zones". I have already 2 subnets in two different AZ. Do you have any idea about this?